# setCellStyle - apply cell style (percent) to matrix using XLConnect

Tags: r, row, col, xlconnect, rep

My question is based on an issue mentioned in a previous question [Formatting of numbers using Mirai's XLConnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306474/formatting-of-numbers-using-mirais-xlconnect). I have trouble implementing this solution from @joran and I think I might not be the only person with this problem.

I want to export a correlation matrix(10x10) to excel. It is saved as a matrix called export.

```
library(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook(paste0("corr_test.xlsx"), create = TRUE)
prcntg <- createCellStyle(wb)
setDataFormat(prcntg, format = "0.00%")
createSheet(wb, name="corr")
writeWorksheet(wb,export,"corr",startRow = 2, startCol = 1, header = TRUE)
setColumnWidth(wb, sheet = "corr", column = 1:30, width = -1)
setCellStyle(wb, sheet = "corr", row= rep(3:12,times=10), col = rep(1:10,     
+times=12), cellstyle = prcntg)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

I have trouble with this line

```
setCellStyle(wb, sheet = "corr", row= rep(3:12,times=10), col = rep(1:10,     
+times=12), cellstyle = prcntg)
```

I don't manage to apply the style to the whole matrix. It is about the arguments *row* and *col* that cause trouble.

The result looks like the picture below.

[image: Output xls]

I've tried an endless number of combinations now. Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do it:

```
rc = expand.grid(row = 3:12, col = 1:10)
setCellStyle(wb, sheet = "corr", row= rc$row, col = rc$col, cellstyle = prcntg)
```